# How do I replace missing values based on median of another value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that looks similar to this:

```
|Budget|Profit |Ranking| #Ranking has values ranging from 1-10 (1 = worst, 10 = best)
|------|-------|-------|
|10000 | NaN   | 8     |
|NaN   | 4000  | 3     |
|5000  | 7000  | 9     |
|12000 | NaN   | 8     |
|2000  | 4500  | 3     |
|5000  | 10000 | 8     |
```

I want to fill the missing values in **Budget** and **Profit** in regards to the median of their corresponding ranking, but can't seem to get it right.

```
for score in range(1, 11):
  median_score = df[df['score'] == score]['budget'].median()
  index_nr = df[df['score'] == score]
  for i in index_nr:
    df.loc[i, :]['budget'].filla(median_score)
```

How can I improve my code so that it fills the missing data with the median of it's rank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the columns' median of each ranking group using `groupby` + `transform`, and then pass it to `fillna`

```
groups_median = df.groupby('Ranking').transform('median')
df = df.fillna(groups_median)
```